# How to add labels value above Barchart Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Matplotlib]

How to add Val above barchart?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('data/FGA Challenge 1/menu.csv') # Read the dataset
df.Category.value_counts()
df.groupby("Category").Calories.mean().round(2)
df.groupby("Category").Calories.mean().round(2).plot.bar(rot=0,figsize=(15,8),color="orange", legend=True
plt.ylabel('Cal')
plt.title('Rata-rata Kalori Untuk Setiap Kategori (Cal)')
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by adding "Val above the bar chart"? Do you want the value to appear above each of the bars?

Comment: Yeah, @Jimmy I want to make values appear on each bars

Comment: Ok it looks like you have the answer. Great!